# Sending Image from Java server to android

Tags: java, android, server, image-upload

I need to send an image from `/home/downloads/pics.jpg` to Android phone. I've seen some info about how to send images from the server to an Android device. For Example : [this link](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/)

Please give me some advice on how to approach this in server part?

Comment: did you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

```
String url = "http://yourserver/image.jpg";
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),
        "yourfile");
try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

    InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
            new FileInputStream(file), -1);
    reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
    reqEntity.setChunked(true); // Send in multiple parts if needed
    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    //Do something with response...

} catch (Exception e) {
    // show error
}
```

Comment: `//Do something with response...`. You should at least add code that reads all from the input stream.

Comment: The androidhive example is for uploading a file. How could that be of help?